# Call-ID for subsequent REGISTER message

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

We have a SIP client based on PJSIP 2.7.1. If I am observing subsequent REGISTER messages (after a specific time the REGISTER is expired and the app sends a new REGISTER) I see that some of these REGISTER messages have the same call-ID. Is that OK?

The background for this question is: in the server logs we see that some SIP messages do not arrive at the server. However, in the client logs we see no error for not sending a SIP message. Bit strange.

BR, Rene

Answer (score 1):

See [section 10.2 of RFC3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-10.2):

> Call-ID: All registrations from a UAC SHOULD use the same Call-ID
> header field value for registrations sent to a particular
> registrar.

You can try a packet sniffer to verify if the SIP client sends SIP messages.